# Grails: Cobertura XML report missing on Sonar

Tags: grails, sonarqube, code-coverage, cobertura, test-coverage

I'm working on a web application using `Grails 2.1.1` and it was requested me to make evidence about the test code coverage.

The project is using:

- Maven 3.0.5
- code-coverage 1.2.7 (grails plugin for Cobertura)
- sonar-maven-plugin 2.5
- SonarQube 3.7.4 (running on localhost)

On my `pom.xml`, there are declared the following sonar's properties:

```
<sonar.language>grvy</sonar.language>        
<sonar.groovy.cobertura.reportPath>target/test-reports/cobertura/coverage.xml</sonar.groovy.cobertura.reportPath>
```

I successfully generate [cobertura.xml](http://nopaste.linux-dev.org/?454663) report inside directory target/test-reports/cobertura, launching the command:

```
grails tA -coverage -xml
```

but when I run:

```
mvn sonar:sonar
```

It isn't displayed any test report on Sonar, although I receive as command response the following output lines:

```
[INFO] [15:20:42.007] Sensor Groovy CoberturaSensor...
[INFO] [15:20:42.007] Analyzing Cobertura report: target/test-reports/cobertura/coverage.xml
[INFO] [15:20:42.086] Sensor Groovy CoberturaSensor done: 79 ms
```

Comment: Give a try to this useful article http://causecode.com/ng/dist/index.html#/blog/show/19

Comment: Thanks a lot, anyway I solved through http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25901059/sonarqube-4-4-not-displaying-cobertura-unit-tests-or-code-coverage-for-grails-2/25901837#25901837